# Alternative mobile templates for a mako+flask-django app

Tags: django, mako

We have an app thats is a fusion of flask and django and it uses mako as a template engine, we want to provide alternative templates in some views for when the user is on mobile, currently the what I have done is to make two sub folders in my templates folder and overide the render method to grab the appropriate mako

```
templates
   mobile
     base.mako
     index.mako
   desktop
     base.mako
     index.mako
     results.mako
```

So for example if I call render("index.mako") and the request has `request.mobile==True` then it will translate the file url to `mobile/index.mako` , if the 'mobile/{some template}.mako' doesn't exist it will automatically grab the 'desktop/{some template}.mako' since all templates exist for the desktop.
The problem now comes with inheritence, say I have the following template

results.mako

```
<%inherit file="base.mako" />
<select>
------
</select>
```

and I call the render("results.mako") with request.mobile==True , the path will translate to desktop/results.mako (since the results.mako doesnt exist for mobile) and the results.mako will inherit from the 'desktop/base.mako'(since it uses the relative path) and not the correct 'mobile/base.mako' which should be used since its a mobile and the mobile/base.mako exists.

Any ideas of how to solve this in an elegant(avoid ifs inside the mako) way? Maybe by changing somehow the dir make thinks the template is located?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by overriding the get_template method of the mako's TemplateLookup object.

```
    #override the template loading function in order to load the mobile ones when needed
    def get_template(self, uri):
        is_mobile_version=False
        has_mobile_view=False;

        u = re.sub(r'^\/+', '', uri).replace("mobile/","").replace("desktop/","")
        for dir in self.directories:
            dir = dir.replace(os.path.sep, posixpath.sep)

            mobile_file = posixpath.normpath(posixpath.join(dir, "mobile/" + u))

            if os.path.isfile(mobile_file):
                has_mobile_view = True

            if (local.request.cookies.get("mobile") == "true"):
                is_mobile_version = True

                local.response_headers['has_mobile_view'] = has_mobile_view
                local.response_headers["mobile"] = True

                if (has_mobile_view):
                    local.response_headers['is_mobile_version'] = is_mobile_version
                    return self._load(mobile_file, "mobile/" + u)

            desktop_file = posixpath.normpath(posixpath.join(dir, "desktop/" + u))
            if (os.path.isfile(desktop_file)):
                return self._load(desktop_file, uri)
            else:
                raise exceptions.TopLevelLookupException(
                    "Cant locate(desktop or mobile) template for uri %r" % uri)
    func_type=type(TemplateLookup.get_template)
    self.template_env.get_template = func_type(get_template, self.template_env, TemplateLookup)
```